# Flutter speech_to_text: ^2.2.0 package Not listening - initialisation problem?

Tags: android, flutter, package, android-studio-3.0

To start using package I have tried the code provided by the developer. 
I am on windows 7 64bit machine, have used nexus 4 and now nexus 5x virtual machine with android 5 and now with Android Q. Apart from that, also a real phone with android 7.0. The phone's on-board text to speech functionality works flawlessly. 
In each of the configurations, the interface does not really appear to respond except when I click initialize - nothing happens with the app except in the Run window of Android Studio. 
Here is the readout:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 64 in debug mode... Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... √ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk. Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk... Flutter is taking longer than expected to report its views. Still trying... Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53319/B_tNUT2pR7I=/ws Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86 64... W/xample.flutter( 5738): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo;->getSourceNodeId()J (greylist, reflection, allowed) W/xample.flutter( 5738): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityRecord;->getSourceNodeId()J (greylist, reflection, allowed) W/xample.flutter( 5738): Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo;->mChildNodeIds:Landroid/util/LongArray; (greylist, reflection, allowed) W/xample.flutter( 5738): Accessing hidden method Landroid/util/LongArray;->get(I)J (greylist, reflection, allowed) I/Choreographer( 5738): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. D/HostConnection( 5738): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x70249825f180, tid 5786 D/HostConnection( 5738): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0  D/HostConnection( 5738): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x702497d3e6a0, tid 5955 D/HostConnection( 5738): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0  D/eglCodecCommon( 5738): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0 D/EGL_emulation( 5738): eglCreateContext: 0x702497d3e740: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3 D/eglCodecCommon( 5738): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0 D/EGL_emulation( 5738): eglCreateContext: 0x70249825f220: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3 D/EGL_emulation( 5738): eglMakeCurrent: 0x70249825f220: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x702498218680) W/Gralloc3( 5738): mapper 3.x is not supported D/HostConnection( 5738): createUnique: call D/HostConnection( 5738): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x70249825f360, tid 5786 D/HostConnection( 5738): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0  D/eglCodecCommon( 5738): allocate: Ask for block of size 0x1000 D/eglCodecCommon( 5738): allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ff807000 size 0x2000 D/HostConnection( 5738): createUnique: call D/HostConnection( 5738): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x702448a9ff00, tid 5955 D/HostConnection( 5738): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0  D/EGL_emulation( 5738): eglMakeCurrent: 0x702497d3e740: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x70244d193360) D/EGL_emulation( 5738): eglMakeCurrent: 0x70249825f220: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x702498218680) D/eglCodecCommon( 5738): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0 I/OpenGLRenderer( 5738): Davey! duration=16105ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=320862128930, Vsync=321745462228, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=321750930400, AnimationStart=321751011720, PerformTraversalsStart=321751071720, DrawStart=330820804190, SyncQueued=331199393480, SyncStart=331258181510, IssueDrawCommandsStart=331421431670, SwapBuffers=336112080650, FrameCompleted=337026255970, DequeueBufferDuration=550559000, QueueBufferDuration=35074000,  I/Choreographer( 5738): Skipped 953 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. D/EGL_emulation( 5738): eglMakeCurrent: 0x702497d3e740: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x70244d193360) D/eglCodecCommon( 5738): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0 I/Choreographer( 5738): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. I/OpenGLRenderer( 5738): Davey! duration=782ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=349271346526, Vsync=349938013166, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=349954335870, AnimationStart=349954427840, PerformTraversalsStart=349997031300, DrawStart=349997268140, SyncQueued=349997407090, SyncStart=350019841510, IssueDrawCommandsStart=350019994270, SwapBuffers=350027291360, FrameCompleted=350076153750, DequeueBufferDuration=149000, QueueBufferDuration=9594000,  I/OpenGLRenderer( 5738): Davey! duration=818ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=350655153383, Vsync=350755153379, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=350758548020, AnimationStart=350758679460, PerformTraversalsStart=350933225780, DrawStart=351140119140, SyncQueued=351140550980, SyncStart=351159859490, IssueDrawCommandsStart=351159930940, SwapBuffers=351165057370, FrameCompleted=351492805850, DequeueBufferDuration=292974000, QueueBufferDuration=727000,  W/xample.flutter( 5738): Verification of androidx.core.view.DragAndDropPermissionsCompat androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.requestDragAndDropPermissions(android.app.Activity, android.view.DragEvent) took 201.593ms E/flutter ( 5738): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(multipleRequests, Only one initialize at a time, null) E/flutter ( 5738): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7) E/flutter ( 5738): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:18) E/flutter ( 5738): <asynchronous suspension> E/flutter ( 5738): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:329:12) E/flutter ( 5738): #3      SpeechToText.initialize (package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart:174:10) E/flutter ( 5738):
#4      _MyAppState.initSpeechState (package:flutter6/main.dart:34:35) E/flutter ( 5738): #5      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:779:19) E/flutter ( 5738):
#6      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:862:36) E/flutter ( 5738):
#7      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24) E/flutter ( 5738): #8      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:504:11) E/flutter ( 5738): #9   BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:282:5) E/flutter ( 5738): #10   BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:217:7) E/flutter ( 5738): #11   PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:475:9) E/flutter ( 5738): #12     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:76:12) E/flutter ( 5738): #13     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122:9) E/flutter ( 5738): #14     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:379:8) E/flutter ( 5738): #15 PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:120:18) E/flutter ( 5738): #16     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:106:7) E/flutter ( 5738): #17     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:19) E/flutter ( 5738):
#18     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22) E/flutter ( 5738):
#19     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7) E/flutter ( 5738):
#20     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7) E/flutter ( 5738):
#21     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7) E/flutter ( 5738):
#22     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1196:13) E/flutter ( 5738): #23     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19) E/flutter ( 5738): #24     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:987:7) E/flutter ( 5738): #25     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:275:10) E/flutter ( 5738): #26    
_dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:184:5) E/flutter ( 5738):  I/Choreographer( 5738): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Android Studio, flutter and node were installed 3 days ago, I have run the flutter doctor with -v and without the parameter. Previously, some licences unsigned, now that is sorted.

Here is the code I pasted from the above page:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_recognition_error.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_recognition_result.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _hasSpeech = false;
  double level = 0.0;
  double minSoundLevel = 50000;
  double maxSoundLevel = -50000;
  String lastWords = "";
  String lastError = "";
  String lastStatus = "";
  String _currentLocaleId = "";
  List<LocaleName> _localeNames = [];
  final SpeechToText speech = SpeechToText();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> initSpeechState() async {
    bool hasSpeech = await speech.initialize(
        onError: errorListener, onStatus: statusListener);
    if (hasSpeech) {
      _localeNames = await speech.locales();

      var systemLocale = await speech.systemLocale();
      _currentLocaleId = systemLocale.localeId;
    }

    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _hasSpeech = hasSpeech;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Speech to Text Example'),
        ),
        body: Column(children: [
          Center(
            child: Text(
              'Speech recognition available',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('Initialize'),
                      onPressed: _hasSpeech ? null : initSpeechState,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('Start'),
                      onPressed: !_hasSpeech || speech.isListening
                          ? null
                          : startListening,
                    ),
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('Stop'),
                      onPressed: speech.isListening ? stopListening : null,
                    ),
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('Cancel'),
                      onPressed: speech.isListening ? cancelListening : null,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    DropdownButton(
                      onChanged: (selectedVal) => _switchLang(selectedVal),
                      value: _currentLocaleId,
                      items: _localeNames
                          .map(
                            (localeName) => DropdownMenuItem(
                          value: localeName.localeId,
                          child: Text(localeName.name),
                        ),
                      )
                          .toList(),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Recognized Words',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        color: Theme.of(context).selectedRowColor,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            lastWords,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned.fill(
                        bottom: 10,
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          child: Container(
                            width: 40,
                            height: 40,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                    blurRadius: .26,
                                    spreadRadius: level * 1.5,
                                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.05))
                              ],
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
                            ),
                            child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.mic),

                                onPressed: () {
                              /*...*/
                            }
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Error Status',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0),
                  ),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text(lastError),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
            color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
            child: Center(
              child: speech.isListening
                  ? Text(
                "I'm listening...",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )
                  : Text(
                'Not listening',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }

  void startListening() {
    lastWords = "";
    lastError = "";
    speech.listen(
        onResult: resultListener,
        listenFor: Duration(seconds: 10),
        localeId: _currentLocaleId,
        onSoundLevelChange: soundLevelListener,
        cancelOnError: true,
        partialResults: true);
    setState(() {});
  }

  void stopListening() {
    speech.stop();
    setState(() {
      level = 0.0;
    });
  }

  void cancelListening() {
    speech.cancel();
    setState(() {
      level = 0.0;
    });
  }

  void resultListener(SpeechRecognitionResult result) {
    setState(() {
      lastWords = "${result.recognizedWords} - ${result.finalResult}";
    });
  }

  void soundLevelListener(double level) {
    minSoundLevel = min(minSoundLevel, level);
    maxSoundLevel = max(maxSoundLevel, level);
    //print("sound level $level: $minSoundLevel - $maxSoundLevel ");
    setState(() {
      this.level = level;
    });
  }

  void errorListener(SpeechRecognitionError error) {
    print("Received error status: $error, listening: ${speech.isListening}");
    setState(() {
      lastError = "${error.errorMsg} - ${error.permanent}";
    });
  }

  void statusListener(String status) {
    print(
        "Received listener status: $status, listening: ${speech.isListening}");
    setState(() {
      lastStatus = "$status";
    });
  }

  _switchLang(selectedVal) {
    setState(() {
      _currentLocaleId = selectedVal;
    });
    print(selectedVal);
  }
}
```

[image: Here is the screenshot of the app screen - looks identical in each of configurations]

I have imported the package by adding a dependency to yaml and importing the pub, and have run out of any further ideas. Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by change `targetSdkVersion` in build.gradle file from 30 to 28.

Answer (score 0):

The application using the speech_to_text plugin requires user permission. You need to add the required keys for iOS in the Info.plist file. For Android, you need to add the record audio permission in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Here is the description of the package:
https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text
Scroll down to "permission". There you can see how to add all said things.